# Which config file converts the login password raw text to hash in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was wondering, which system file converts the user entered raw text into the hash for validating the password in shadow file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your average Linux distro with PAM, the password is validated against the shadow file by `pam_unix.so`. This library leverages `libcrypt.so` to do the actual hashing.